# No linebreak with two divs

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS so please be patient with me. What I am trying to achieve is, the following,

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit: **Click on me**

When clicked, the bold text creates a pop-up. Now here's my problem. I am getting a newline between the paragraph and **Click on me** which I do not want. My code is as follows,

## HTML

```
<div class="panel overflow-hidden">
  {{ range.Site.Params.publication.list }}
  <p class="text-dark">
    <i class="far fa-newspaper"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit: - 
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><span style="font-weight:bold">Click on me</span>
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
    </div>
  </p> 
  {{ end }}
</div>
```

## CSS for popup class

```
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

Please help

Comment: You can't insert a div inside a p tag

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: using a span instead of a div

Comment: Apologies, but since I am new can you post an answer so that I can understand better. Like the same code works with span instead of the internal div?

Comment: Yes, it does thank you so much !!!!

Comment: @Sfili_81 can you also tell me how can I adjust the popup height in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207247/discussion-between-arnab-sanyal-and-sfili-81).

Answer (score 1):

**I'm not getting your question but if you want to use a link in same line then you can do like this :**

HTML

```html
<i class="far fa-newspaper"></i> 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.
<a class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"> 
<strong>Click on me</strong></a>
```

Here I have just copied your code on stackblitz.com,
I hope you get my point here is the code : 
[Code:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxk31v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I personally think to create a dialog you need to create an overlay which takes whole screen then the container is laid out in center of screen. Here is the demonstration and live example:

HTML

```html
<div class="dialog-overlay">
  <div class="dialog-container">
     Your dialog content goes here!
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.dialog-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.dialog-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 94%;
    padding: 24px 20px;
}
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/kenwheeler/pen/LvGjK?editors=0110)